# How do I connect GitHub Enterprise in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, github, android-studio-3.0, github-enterprise

Currently, I am using Github enterprise and I have the domain host like

> https://github.myhub.mycompany.com

I can fetch the repository in my terminal using ssh but I cant do it in Android Studio. Everytime it showed "401 bad credentials", am I doing wrong?

```
Host : github.myhub.mycompany.com

Login : user

Password : user
```

[image]